# Safari not triggering onclick on parent div

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have this code

```
   <div onclick='onClick();'>

     <select id='select'>

          <option>Option1</option>

          <option>Option2</option>

     </select>

   </div>
```

when the user clicks on the select dropdown the onclick even of parent div is not triggered. It seems to be working fine all other browsers.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

On Safari can you check dimension of parent div? Maybe you didn't tap on it

Comment: It is not that i have to tap on the div. In other browsers if i tap on the select dropdown  the parent div onclick fires but not on safari.